# Using Keytool in InitContainer

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, containers, keytool

I am trying to import corporate certificate, so that Java/Spark will be correctly authorizing to access the corporate Cluster.

For this I'm building an Image in Docker and deploy it with kubernetes. I don't want to copy the file in the Dockerfile, because I think it should be a secret file. Thus I'm forcing myself to not execute `keytool` inside my dockerfile.

Also, I don't want to run as root my application container, in case if there is a security issue, the usee could potentially access to everything as root.

I'm trying to use an InitContainer to load the certificate. This it is a totally separate container that would run as root to execute `keytool`. By default it will save the new file at `~/.keystore`. Since it's a separate container, it won't be find by my applicative container. So I try to change the default directory for `keytool` and to point it to a mounted volume.

Part of Dockerfile:

```
FROM Our_corporate_base_image

ENV JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk"
ENV _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/work-dir/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/work-dir/truststore.jks"
USER root
WORKDIR /opt

RUN curl -L -o openjdk.tar.gz https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/13/GPL/openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz \
  && mkdir jdk \
  && tar zxf openjdk.tar.gz -C jdk --strip-components=1 \
  && rm -rf openjdk.tar.gz \
  && apt-get -y --purge autoremove curl \
  && ln -sf /opt/jdk/bin/* /usr/local/bin/ \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && java  --version \
  && javac --version \
  && jlink --version
```

When building the image, it tells me the JVM does take into account my `_JAVA_OPTIONS` (I think I should use `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`)

```
19:02:23 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/work-dir/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/work-dir/truststore.jks
19:02:23 openjdk 11.0.1 2018-10-16
19:02:23 OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
19:02:23 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
19:02:23 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/work-dir/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/work-dir/truststore.jks
19:02:24 javac 11.0.1
19:02:24 Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/work-dir/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/work-dir/truststore.jks
19:02:24 11.0.1
```

`/work-dir/` is a mounted volume in my app container and init container:

```
  initContainers:
  - name: "{{ k8s.deploy.name }}-init"
    image: imageRepo
    imagePullPolicy: "Always"
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 0
    command: ['/bin/bash']
    args: ['-c', "env && keytool -import -alias ca-bundle -file {{ k8s.mountpath.secret }}/ca-bundle.crt -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -noprompt"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: "{{ k8s.volumemounts.secret }}"
      mountPath: "{{ k8s.mountpath.secret }}/"
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: "/work-dir"
  containers:
  - name: "{{ k8s.deploy.name }}-app"
    image: imageRepo
    imagePullPolicy: "Always"
    // Lot of other stuff to set app and variables and launch a script for the app
    volumeMounts:
    - name: workdir
      mountPath: "/work-dir"
```

When I deploy the solution, the Init container does launch and execute the command as root.
In `kubectl` I get logs saving it is at least importing the java options and the cert file:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/work-dir/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/work-dir/truststore.jks
Certificate was added to keystore
```

When I run a `bash` in the app container to `keytool -list`:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/work-dir/keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/work-dir/truststore.jks
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: /home/user/.keystore
```

So I'm kind of confuse on how `keytool` works since the documentation does explicitly says that I need to modify `Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore` and `Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` to change the default location of `keytool` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablqy/index.html

Is it that my JVM does not take into account the options? I don't want to use the `-keystore` option in `keytool` to specify the location of the file while importing the cert file. Else I don't think java will load it nativly.

Should I try to mount a volume at `/home/user/`?

Comment: Unless I totally missed what your are trying to do, I don't really get why you would put so much precaution around adding a public custom Certificate Authority to your image/java trust store (note: even if you don't publish that CA to the outside, it is still public information i.e. not secret). The only thing I would do is change the default key-store secret (which is `changeme` for java if I remember well) and keep it secret under the build environment so that it cannot be altered during run. Note that anyone able to pull you image will always be able to replace it anyway.

Comment: My predecesor used XLDeploy to send the certificate file with a secret. I thought it was a good thing to keep it this way. But If you tell it's not like a private key in ssh, then yes, sure I'll do in Dockerfile

Comment: You java keystore can contain many different information: private keys, public keys and certificates, secret keys... It is a good idea to have this overall protected especially if you have any of the secret parts. Here (once again unless I missed something....) we are only talking about adding there a public certificate. If your only need a keystore containing the market's known CAs + your custom one and no other secrets, it can be included in your image directly.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation.